# AFNetworking 5 - NetworkReachabilityManager Listener

Tags: swift, alamofire

I recently upgraded from AFNetworking 4 to 5.

This was the old way of initializing the listener:

```
let net = NetworkReachabilityManager()

net?.listener = { status in
if net?.isReachable ?? false {

switch status {

    case .reachable(.ethernetOrWiFi):
        print("The network is reachable over the WiFi connection")

    case .reachable(.wwan):
        print("The network is reachable over the WWAN connection")

    case .notReachable:
        print("The network is not reachable")

    case .unknown :
        print("It is unknown whether the network is reachable")

    }
}

net?.startListening()
```

The new documentation reads this:

```
@discardableResult
open func startListening(onQueue queue: DispatchQueue = .main,
                         onUpdatePerforming listener: @escaping Listener) -> Bool
```

https://alamofire.github.io/Alamofire/Classes/NetworkReachabilityManager.html

In my code, I am trying this:

```
let listener = NetworkReachabilityManager.Listener()

self.reachabilityManager?.startListening(onUpdatePerforming: listener){


}
```

The compilation error I am getting is `Extra argument 'onUpdatePerforming' in call`. It is a syntactical issue, I am transitioning form Objective C to Swift.

What I attempt to pass a closure, I also cannot seem to get the syntax correct:

```
   self.reachabilityManager?.startListening(onUpdatePerforming: { (NetworkReachabilityManager.Listener) in


    })
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Listener` is just a `typealias` for the closure type expected, so you need to pass a closure.

```swift
self.reachabilityManager?.startListening { status in
    switch status {
    ...
    }
}
```

Comment: I've added an example.

Comment: Thanks, yes, I was able to figure it out eventually from scouring the syntax of other closures. I still do not understand why "status" comes after the "{" however.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the code which runs after the AFNetworking update:

```
    self.reachabilityManager?.startListening(onUpdatePerforming: {networkStatusListener in

        print("Network Status Changed:", networkStatusListener)

           switch networkStatusListener {
           case .notReachable:
               self.presentAlert(message: "The network is not reachable. Please reconnect to continue using the app.")
                       print("The network is not reachable.")
               case .unknown :
                       self.presentAlert(message: "It is unknown whether the network is reachable. Please reconnect.")
                       print("It is unknown whether the network is reachable.")
               case .reachable(.ethernetOrWiFi):
                       print("The network is reachable over the WiFi connection")

               case .reachable(.cellular):
                       print("The network is reachable over the WWAN connection")
        }

    })
```