# Type of expression is ambiguous without more context, Missing argument for parameter 'onUpdatePerforming' in call

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I have never written in swift, first time in my life I opened xCode. But I really need to make a build of one project, which is even available in the AppStore. Now faced such problem. Please help me fix it or push me to the right solution.

```
import Foundation
import Alamofire

class NetworkManager {
    
    static let shared = NetworkManager()
    
    let reachabilityManager = Alamofire.NetworkReachabilityManager(host: "api.locutus.app")
    
    func startNetworkReachabilityObserver() {
        reachabilityManager?.listener = { status in
            switch status {
            case .notReachable:
              AppLog.verbose("The network is not reachable")
            case .unknown:
              AppLog.verbose("It is unknown whether the network is reachable")
            case .reachable(.ethernetOrWiFi):
              AppLog.verbose("The network is reachable over the WiFi connection")
            case .reachable(.wwan):
              AppLog.verbose("The network is reachable over the WWAN connection")
            }
        }
        reachabilityManager?.startListening()
    }
    
    public func isReachable() -> Bool {
        if reachabilityManager!.isReachable {
            return true
        } else {
            return false
        }
    }
}
```

Errors:

```
reachabilityManager?.listener = { status in - Type of expression is ambiguous without more context

reachabilityManager?.startListening() Missing argument for parameter 'onUpdatePerforming' in call
```

Comment: The method is `func startListening(onQueue queue: DispatchQueue = .main, onUpdatePerforming listener: @escaping Listener) -> Bool`  See https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/blob/master/Source/NetworkReachabilityManager.swift

Comment: So it should be `reachabilityManager?.startListening {status in switch status {...} }`, no?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [AFNetworking 5 - NetworkReachabilityManager Listener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58238950/afnetworking-5-networkreachabilitymanager-listener)

Comment: @Larme How is this different from what it is now? I think it's 1 in 1.

Comment: @udi no, it creates new errors

Comment: "@Larme How is this different from what it is now? I think it's 1 in 1. – " Because that how it should be written? If you prefer `reachabilityManager?.startListening(onUpdatePerforming: { status in switch status { ... } })`

Comment: `NetworkReachabilityManager` has no property `listener`, so it doesn't make sense. It uses its private `mutableState` which has a `listener` property, but it doesn't have it one itself. And the `startListening()` method, is in fact `startListening(onQueue: onUpdatePerforming:)`, it has two parameters (the first one can be ommittted if you use the default value), which second one is mandatory.